# Why does Eclipse JDT Null-Checking respect Apache Commons Validate

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, non-nullable, null-check

I use @NonNull-Checking with Eclipse-JDT and was very pleased to see that it understands and respects the use of Apache Commons Validate. Which means in code:

```
Validate.notNull(someInput);
@NonNull String a = someInput;
```

Without the first line the second one produces a warning in Eclipse.
I can only configure if "assert" should be respected.
But without any further notice it also respects Validate#notNull and Objects#requireNonNull.
This is great but I wonder:

1. Is it hardcoded or configurable (in some plugin, file,...) which frameworks/methods Eclipse respects for proper Null-Checking?
2. Can I write my own methods to let Eclipse know, some variable is guaranteed to be non-null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is hard coded and can't be extended (other than by modifying the source  code).

Some of the main classes involved as in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup` and `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast` including the `TypeConstants` and `TypeIds` interfaces and the `ReferenceBinding` and `MessageSend` classes.

Comment: Thx. I didn't find documentation about this. Is there a full list of the supported frameworks/methods?

Comment: I don't know of a list, you can work it out by looking at the source code but that is also difficult to read.

Comment: @greg-449 well researched. Let me just add a link to the bug via which most of this was added: https://bugs.eclipse.org/382069#c6 . I admit, though, that this is not proper documentation ...

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Its a shame this is hardcoded. I realize doing the real analysis would be too expensive but perhaps an extensions of the EEA format would allow quick analysis. For example: Right now its 0 = Nullable and 1 = NonNull. What could be added is 4 more types: 2 for nullable/nonnull void like methods and 2 for nullable/nonnull for boolean like methods.

Comment: @AdamGent, Your idea goes beyond the aim of **external** annotations, we would first need to define additional annotation types for specifying different (null-)contracts. Feel free to file an RFE in bugzilla. Once a new annotation is specified, representing it in EEA would be straight-forward. Unfortunately, experience tells that specifying new annotations with agreement of all parties involved is a hard nut to crack. E.g. see that `@LazyNonNull` has been proposed long ago, and still we don't have strong agreement that this would be a worthwhile addition.