# Eclipse JDT Null Pointer analysis appears to have special behavior for Objects.requireNonNull that can't be replicated

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Eclipse has null pointer annotation analysis and you can attach external annotations. http://www.lastnpe.org/ has documentation on that in case you stumble here and are confused.

Anyway if I attach the JDK external annotations (also known as *.eea files) and turn on the annotation analysis I can do the following (assume someObject is `@Nullable`):

```java
Objects.requireNonNull(someObject);
someObject.toString() // No error/warning here as Eclipse apparently figured out that someObject isn't null.
```

The eea definition of `requireNonNull` is:

```
requireNonNull
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>(TT;)TT;
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>(T0T;)T1T;
```

Now if I make my own library lets call it MyObjects and attach the source and annotation (exactly like Objects.requireNonNull) I get a warning when I do the above:

```
MyObjects.likeRequireNonNull(someObject);
someObject.toString() // NP analysis warning/error here
```

Obviously I can get around it by re-assigning:

```
someObject = MyObjects.likeRequireNonNull(someObject);
someObject.toString(); // No error or warning.
```

but in some cases that isn't desirable (lambdas).

The above makes since because someObject is now being reassigned to a `@NonNull`.

What doesn't make since is how I can replicate the behavior of `Objects.requireNonNull` where I don't need to assign it back. I can't figure out how Eclipse knows via the external annotations that `Objects.requireNonNull` will guarantee the input variable not to be null in later usage.

---

EDIT: Apparently Objects.requireNonNull might be on a special whitelist according to this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=553272

Comment: Yes, there is an internal list of known methods as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51655802/2670892). MessageSend.detectAssertionUtility seems to be the method that does this check

Comment: Yes its a shame you can't customize it. It seems the EEA format could be extended such that more types could be added. Right now its 0 = Nullable and 1 = NonNull. What could be added is 4 more types: 2 for nullable/nonnull void like methods and 2 for nullable/nonnull for boolean like methods.